# Notification click do not open desired activity

Tags: android, firebase, android-pendingintent

In my app, depending upon which notifications appears, a corresponding activity must open. In short there are more than one pending intents. Even though the activities are assigned, on clicking the notification it takes me to the launching activity instead of the desired activity.

```
    private void sendNotification(final String notificationTitle, final String notificationBody) {
            if (notificationTitle.equals("Mango")) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, Mango.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pendingIntent(notificationTitle, notificationBody, intent, INT = 100);

                    } else if (notificationTitle.equals("Orange")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, Orange.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pendingIntent(notificationTitle, notificationBody, intent, INT = 1);
                    }


 public void pendingIntent(String notificationTitle, String notificationBody, Intent intent , final int INT){

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(INT, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

       // PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, INT, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
        notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)   //Automatically delete the notification
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) //Notification icon
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationBody);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(INT, notificationBuilder.build());

    }

                }
```